Replace the querystring of an href declaration in an <a> tag
I want to replace the following hyperlinks dynamically
from
<a href="/xsearch2?q=some search/21">21</a>

to
<a href="/xsearch2?q=some search&page=21">21</a>

How can I do that dynamically? I have tried the following:
preg_replace(
    '#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i',
    '<a href="/xsearch2?q=' . $key . '&page=$1">$1</a>',
    $pagination
);

but it's changing the hyperlinks also, just want to remove the last slash / from hyperlinks and add &page=.

Just need to ask, is it possible to solve this by changing what is generating it this way?

This is not a job which needs or should implement regex.  Is this input text part of a larger string/document? or is this the whole isolated string?

What happens when the user adds a forward slash to the some search string?

It is unclear what you're working with. You just don't tell. I can guess from the single line of code that the input is a string, called $pagination. So how did you end up with this hyperlink in a string? Where the rest of the code? Are you planning to use urlencode() on the $key?

I have voted to reopen because: 1. Despite personally asking for deeper context to better understand the potential nuances of the task, there is a clear [mcve] in the question. 2. To the trained eye (and as indicated by my answer), this task is best accomplished using a medley of parsing tools, but from the asker's perspective the task is very narrow and direct (because it technically can be satisfied by a simple regex). 3. Too often the community prefers to close un-attempted tasks as NMF, but this question indeed contains a coding attempt. There are thousands of far worse questions on SO.

@mickmackusa I somewhat agree with you. I will also vote to reopen as soon as it is clear that this question isn't abandoned, like many of them are nowadays.

"abandonment" is not a qualifying criteria for determining if a question is suitable for Stack Overflow.  If we closed and/or kept closed pages because the asker went away, 90% of this site (or more) would be closed.

There are several points of best practice involved in this seemingly innocuous task.

When parsing HTML, use a legitimate DOM parsing tool (like DOMDocument) instead of regex.
When parsing a URL, use a legitimate URL parsing tool (like parse_url()) instead of regex.
When parsing a URL's query string, use a legitimate query string parsing tool (like parse_str()) instead of regex
When building a query string for a URL (especially, one being printed to an HTML document), use a legitimate query string builder tool (like http_build_query()).

More considerations and safeguards can be implemented, but with your current example, I believe this uses the most reliable/reasonable tools rather than seeking shortcuts. Demo
$html = <<<HTML
<a href="/xsearch2?q=some search/21">21</a>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
['path' => $path, 'query' => $qs] = parse_url($a->getAttribute('href'));
parse_str($qs, $qsArray);
if (isset($qsArray['q']) && preg_match('#(.*)/(\d+)$#', $qsArray['q'], $m)) {
    $qsArray['q'] = $m[1];
    $qsArray['page'] = $m[2];
    $a->setAttribute('href', "$path?" . http_build_query($qsArray));
    $html = $dom->saveHTML();
}
echo $html;

Output:
<a href="/xsearch2?q=some+search&amp;page=21">21</a>


What you should definitely NOT do is be tempted by the unreliable shortcut of a single preg_replace() call (even if it does work). Demo
$html = <<<HTML
<a href="/xsearch2?q=some search/21">21</a>
HTML;

echo preg_replace('#/(\d+)(?=">)#', '&page=$1', $html, 1);

Like most innocent-ish regex patterns, this one will work... until it doesn't.
